# Why in a phone call we use "this is" instead of "I am"?

Tags: telephone, idioms

Why is the right form

> Hello, **this is** yzT from english.stackechange.com.

instead of

> Hello, **I’m** yzT from english.stackexchange.com.

I guess non-natives tend to use the latter due to literal translation, but why do natives use the former? You are identifying yourself, telling who you **are**; that’s why I don’t understand why the latter is wrong.

Comment: I am curious too to find answers of natives. Interesting question! :)

Comment: When calling, people don't care who *you* are, per se; they care who this person that picked up the phone is. (People would also ask *Who's this?*, not *Who are you?* if they didn't recognize the speaker's voice.)

Comment: @onomatomaniak: That's the other way round, and is common in AmE but not BrE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"I am" refers to my self, as a being; I was (existed) before I started the call.   "This" refers to the caller, who was not the caller before he called.   Actually, "this" could also refer to a recipient, or any other 'telecommunicative-endpoint' (such as a radio operator).   Note that "this" covers situations where "I" would not be appropriate.   For example:

"This is the operator."
"This is the police."
"This is reception, how may I direct your call?"
"This is the USS Intrepid."

Also note that in most German-speaking countries, "here" is often used ("Smith here.").   (Where else would I be, if not 'here'?)

Comment: Oh, also - 'I am' wouldn't be *wrong*, just unusual and somewhat awkward