# "This is ..." vs. "I am ..." on a Voice Recording

Tags: expression-choice

I know that it's better to use "This is Neeku." instead of "I am Neeku." on a phone conversation. However I need to record a voice sample about my skills and experience, etc. for an interview and upload it to the application form. Which one shall I use in this context?

I did see this question: [Why in a phone call we use "this is" instead of "I am"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111570/why-in-a-phone-call-we-use-this-is-instead-of-i-am) but I still can't tell which is more suitable for my situation. Or shall I even go with "Neeku here." instead of the two other?

P.S. This is an *audio* recording, and it's for a language-related job.

Comment: I think "I am Neeku" would be better on a video introducing yourself. "This is Neeku" seems to presuppose that the listened is familiar with you. Imagine you were introducing yourself at a party to someone who's never met you. You'd use "I am..." rather than "This is..." Also, you'll probably want to contract "I am" into "I'm," since it sounds more natural.

Comment: @Silenus I didn't mention video at any point. It's a ***voice*** recording.

Comment: Yeah I just realized this! Sorry about that. I still think "I am..." is better, although, if you've sent materials to the employer before and they are already familiar with you and your name, "This is..." could work as well.

Comment: Also, starting a conversation or introduction with "I am..." is a bit unconventional. You might want to say "Hi" or "Hey there" to start. For example, "Hi, I'm Neeku". or "Hey there, I'm Neeku" or "Dear __, I'm Neeku" (depending on how informal you want to be).

Comment: @Silenus Again, I did not mention **starting** the conversation with that in my post. Thanks for your effort, though. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a voice recording I would slightly favor "This is Neeku," as short for "This is Neeku speaking."  If you are visible (in person or on video) you don't need to tell them who is speaking, but you need to tell them who you are.

In your specific circumstance, though, I might consider "My name is Neeku," as this fits well with other facts about you, e.g., "My name is Neeku and I recently earned by PhD in . . . ."